# Win32 compatibility with dll files of windows OS

Tags: c, winapi, abi

In writing Win32 applications, most compilers or linkers (e.g. GCC that comes with Code::Blocks, Visual studio 2015, Visual studio 2017) successfully call system dll files. (I understand all win32 app need to call Windows's own dll in order to run)

**Question**
"Is it because of consistent or stable ABI of C language?", which means that GCC's C compiler or Microsoft C compiler (in various VS versions) or any other C compiler, can call dll files of either windows 10 or windows 7.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is. Consistent ABI and API.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.